# replace a text using pdfbox for PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have 4 pdf files that came from one .doc file and I use 4 methods to convert my doc to a pdf (foxite reader, nitro, webservice and Word).

Then I used pdfbox to search and replace some words. The problem is, for some reason it only works for the file from foxite reader and Word, but not for the files created by nitro and the webservice.
Can any one have a clue?

This is the code I used:

```
public static void replace(String s) {
    PDDocument doc = null;
    int occurrences = 0;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(s); // Input PDF File Name
        System.out.println("+e" + doc);
        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog()
                .getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
            // System.out.println("ddd");
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
            parser.parse();
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();
            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                // System.out.println("jjjj");
                Object next = tokens.get(j);
                if (next instanceof PDFOperator) {
                    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;
                    // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF
                    if (op.getOperation()
                            .equals("Tj")) {
                        // Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                        // to display so lets update that operator
                        COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        String string = previous.getString();
                        if (string.contains("#signature#")) {
                            string = string.replace("#signature#", "sam");
                            occurrences++;
                        }
                        // Word you want to change.
                        // Currently this code changes word "Good" to "Bad"
                        previous.reset();
                        previous.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                    } else if (op.getOperation()
                            .equals("TJ")) {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        COSString temp = new COSString();

                        String tempString = "";
                        for (int t = 0; t < previous.size(); t++) {

                            if (previous.get(t) instanceof COSString) {
                                tempString += ((COSString) previous.get(t)).getString();

                            }
                        }

                        temp.append(tempString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                        tempString = "";
                        tempString = temp.getString();
                        if (tempString.contains("#signature#")) {
                            tempString = tempString.replace("#signature#", "sam");
                            occurrences++;
                        }
                        previous.clear();

                        String[] stringArray = tempString.split(" ");

                        for (String string : stringArray) {
                            COSString cosString = new COSString();
                            string = string + " ";
                            cosString.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                            previous.add(cosString);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the page content stream.
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
            tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
            page.setContents(updatedStream);
        }
        System.out.println("number of matches found: " + occurrences);
        doc.save(s + "_convert.pdf"); // Output file name
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("eee+" + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            try {
                doc.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is why it work for some file and not for other file ? should i use someting else when i convert my files to pdf or something else ??

Comment: See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html "Why was the ReplaceText example removed?"

Comment: Simply said your code considers only very trivial options of creating pdfs. It assumes in particular that fonts use an ASCII'ish encoding and that kerning is not applied.

Comment: so there is any API could do this change for all trivial options of creating pdfs?? itext ??